# Resolved: Editing programmatically created UserForm's Code Module resets project

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am deleting original post for issue has somewhat grown into a more general issue with dynamically created Excel VBA userforms that I have detailed [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/solution-workaround-for-dynamically-created-userforms-resetting-project-on-customization.1221593/)

Comment: Modeless means the code keeps going once the form is shown, where modal halts code execution. Since the form is declared locally within the sub and the code keeps going after the form is shown, the form is terminated once the sub is over. Try declaring it at module level, outside the sub (private), and instantiate/show it from the sub.

Comment: I have tried and din't work either. Also, following your explanation, modeless should terminate form at all time, even if I don't touch code module. But creation and display works perfectly if no addition to code module:(  Not to mention that the form doesn't get terminated, once sub has finished. On the contrary, once the form is created, it remains in project forever or until removed.

Comment: @KostasK. turns out modeless vs modal wasn't the real issue. Modeless, finishing the procedure as you said, just reveals the issue quicker.