# Edit a Code Module Programmatically without Unloading the Project's Userforms

Tags: excel, vba, module, edit, userform

Start with a Blank Book1.xlsm Project, and add a Modeless UserForm1 (ie ShowModal set to False)

In the VBE Immediate Window, type "UserForm1.Show" then press "Enter" to show UserForm1

You can now **Manually** Edit Code Modules and **UserForm1 usually Remains Loaded** & Visible
(as long as the code you add doesn't mess with UserForm1 itself)

eg add a comment "'Manual Comment" to Sheet1's Code Module

BUT, if you do a similar edit **Programmatically, UserForm1 gets Hidden and Unloaded**

eg Show UserForm1 again, then from the Immediate Window run;

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("Sheet1").CodeModule.AddFromString "'Prog Comment"
```

Is there any way to prevent this happening, rather than the obvious workaround of Re-Showing the UserForm after doing any Programmatic Edits?

The following post deals also deals with this issue; it is marked as "Resolved", but in my opinion it is rather a complex workaround and I'm hoping there's a direct, and much simpler, solution

[Gabor's Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74325625/resolved-editing-programmatically-created-userforms-code-module-resets-project)